# System.ArgumentException illegal characters in path

Tags: .net, exception, argumentexception, illegal-characters, path-combine

I am using `Path.Combine`, and one of the strings contain a Unicode characters. I get `{System.ArgumentException} exception; illegal characters in path`.

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247.aspx) filepath/name can have unicode characters. Why do I get this exception?

#### Edit:

Here is the code:

```
Path.Combine("C:\PDM\Silver","Amabel Bender QQQ")
```

Comment: Probably easier if we can see the code...

Comment: Could you post the path in question?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I figured out the problem. The second string contains a "tab" character in it causing the exception. (that didn't showed up when I pasted the string here)

Thanks everyone and sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I just posted the exact same suggestion at the same time :)

Answer (score 3):

You may have [double quotes](http://www.mail-archive.com/nant-developers@lists.sourceforge.net/msg05235.html) in your set of paths, since [`Path.InvalidPathChars`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.invalidpathchars.aspx) includes double-quotes.

That would make your exception unrelated to your Unicode character...

---

Just saw your edit of your question: VB, no quotes.

So may be you have a non-printable character copied in your second string, which looks like a space, just before your 'QQQ' string ?
Try also if `"Amabel BenderQQQ"` or `"AmabelBenderQQQ"` work (just to test if it is related to 'QQQ' chars or to the space)

Answer (score 2):

If you are using C# then I'm sure you need to escape the back-slashes

```
Path.Combine("C:\\PDM\\Silver","Amabel Bender QQQ")
```

not applicable if you are using VB though...