# ASP.NET MVC - Illegal characters in path - redirect from Application_Error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, illegal-characters, application-error

In my application I generated few url which contained " (double quotes), unfortunately.
I corrected the url's but google bot already indexed wrong urls.

Now I get quite often following exception:
System.ArgumentException: Illegal characters in path.

The only one place I can catch the error is the Application_Error in the Global.asax - I clean up the url over there and try to redirect to correct url - unfortunately it is not working... The application is not redirecting and I don't know why... Any suggestions?

Comment: did you see that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/367797/system-argumentexception-illegal-characters-in-path ?

Comment: @Aristos: It is not relevant to my issue... I know what character is causing the problem - I clean up url but can't redirect to corrected url..